# Is there anyway to prevent for git to completely delete the contents of a file?

Tags: git, undo

I don't know the main reason but once in a while `git` completely removes the content in a buffer/file that I am working on if the commit is not completed successfully.

After file's content is cleaned, file's [undo-tree](https://github.com/apchamberlain/undo-tree.el) is not able to fetch the latest changes using `emacs` as well, instead its tree is completely empty. I am not able to find the latest changes I have and they do not show up in `stash`.

In the background: zsh's [git auto-fetch](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/tree/master/plugins/git-auto-fetch) is running, I am not sure would that have any affect.

---

=> Is there anyway to prevent for `git` to completely delete the content of a file?

---

- The file (`scripts/lib.py`) is not located in the `.gitignore` or `~/.gitignore_global`.
- `git check-ignore -v -- scripts/lib.py` returns empty
- Please note that the file remains as it is with 0 bytes

```
❯ ls -lA -tr -h | grep lib.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 alper alper    0 2021-01-04 22:09 lib.py
```

Comment: If you want a concrete answer, you should probably tell us what the file is called, whether it matches any pattern in your `.gitignore`, and the output of the `clean` and `check-ignore` commands described in the existing answer. Also whether your `undo-tree` is using a persistent undo history file, what _that_ is called, and whether _it_ is affected by those commands.

Comment: "The file is not located in the .gitignore or ~/.gitignore_global": only a git check-ignore can confirm that: did you try a git check-ignore?

Comment: OK, so could you edit your question with more details, as illustrated by Userless' useful comment? OS version, GIt version, are there any other files affected?

Comment: So you're using Git plugins, Emacs plugins, and some file gets randomly cleared (not removed) while you're doing something. Can you paint a more complete picture of your setup? What do you mean by _"if the commit is not completed successfully"_, what course of actions do you take exactly to end up in this situation? I wouldn't suspect Git to clean a random file's contents, but either your editor or any of the other tools that interact with the filesystem.

Comment: @CodeCaster Yes, before the commit when I do `git diff`, I see all the contents of the file is removed and I cannot undo to its previous version. This is done usually to the latest file that I am working on, which is opened by the `emacs`.

Comment: But a `git diff` showing an empty file does not mean that Git cleared that file. It may have happened long before, by some other process. If you can't explain everything that's going on, we can't help. I would not suspect Git.

Comment: @CodeCaster You are right seems like it is not done by git. I feel like when `emacs` is crashed it may swap out the file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if your file would be deleted by a [`git clean -ndx`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean) (the `-n` is important: it will preview what would be deleted, instead of actually deleting any file)

Check also if that same file is ignored:

```
git check-ignore -v -- the/temp/file
```

(It could be ignored by a [global `core.exclude` file](https://simpleit.rocks/git/make-git-ignore-temporary-files-produced-by-emacs-and-vim-in-all-directories-globally/))

In both cases, that would point to a recurrent `git clean` as a possible cause for the file deletion.

Since the check-ignore did not return anything, that points to a root cause external to Git, more linked to Emacs, as the OP points out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65578478/is-there-anyway-to-prevent-for-git-to-completely-delete-the-contents-of-a-file/65578803#comment115950359_65578478).